# Possible to use hibernate uuid generator independently

Tags: java, hibernate

I am wondering if it is possible to use the hibernate id generator (uuid strategy) by itself to get an id independently of an entity save?

Basically, I am saving record data in two disparate systems. The first is a plain old hibernate record where I am currently using the auto generated uuid strategy for the id field. In the second system I need to use that same uuid as one of the identifier fields.

I currently save the hibernate entity to get the id and then lay down the 2nd record in a different system. The problem is the 2nd system save operation can sometime fail for a variety of reasons. If this happens then I need to delete the hibernate entity.

I was hoping I could clean up the code by generating the id without saving an entity in hibernate, save the data in the remote system, and then save the hibernate entity with the id if everything went well.

I know I can generate a uuid outside of hibernate and then use an assign strategy but I really wanted to use the built in hibernate uuid generator.

Any ideas?

Comment: 'I really wanted to use the built in hibernate uuid generator.' Why? What is special about the UUIDs generated by Hibernate? My guess is that it delegates to `java.util.UUID` in the background.

Comment: Consistency of the uuid generation strategy is the only thing special about it. java.util.UUID is what I am now using since writing the original question but it does generate a uuid of a different form then hibernate. Valid but different.